# Using fullWidth in SimpleForm or TabbedForm to get two columns in react-admin

Tags: material-ui, react-admin

My primary objective is an edit form with two columns. I understand I can do this with a custom form, but I'm wondering if there's an easier way to do it using the existing SimpleForm or (better yet) TabbedForm.

I'm able to get the data to display in two columns using Grid or Box, but it's all crammed into a small column on the left side, instead of using the full width. I've tried playing with fullWidth, changing the component, etc. but I can't get it to work. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Updating with current code:

```js
        <SimpleForm >
            <Grid container spacing={1}>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                    <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>Old</Typography>
                    <TextField source="id" />
                    <TextInput source="foo" fullWidth />
                    <TextInput source="bar" fullWidth />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                    <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>New</Typography>
                    <TextField source="id" fullWidth />
                    <TextInput source="newFoo" fullWidth />
                    <TextInput source="newBar" fullWidth />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </SimpleForm>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this add custom style to grid to take full width

```js
        <SimpleForm >
            <Grid container spacing={1} style={{ width: "100%" }}>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                    <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>Old</Typography>
                    <TextField source="id" />
                    <TextInput source="foo" fullWidth />
                    <TextInput source="bar" fullWidth />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                    <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>New</Typography>
                    <TextField source="id" fullWidth />
                    <TextInput source="newFoo" fullWidth />
                    <TextInput source="newBar" fullWidth />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </SimpleForm>
```